# Getting a rogue iteration from my .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just learning ruby on rails and following this guide roughly: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I have this loop on achievement results (comments in the guide example):

```
<h2>Completed results (<%= @achievement.achievement_results.count %>)</h2>
<% @achievement.achievement_results.each do |result| %>
<p>
    <b>ID:</b>
    <%= result.id %>
</p>
<p>
    <b>Success:</b>
    <%= result.success %>
</p>
<p>
    <b>User:</b>
    <%= result.user_id %>
</p>
<p><%= link_to 'Delete', [result.achievement, result], confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></p>
<hr/>
<% end %>
```

This is in the show view for an achievement and when I load that view, I see an extra iteration of the loop with null values for the result fields. This happens even when the array is [] (checked using rails console to make sure that the array is empty).

Achievement model:

```
class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :achievement_results, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: I don't see how; check the DB.

Comment: Show us the model of @achievement. What does the `@achievement.achievement_results.count` in this view return, 1 or 0?

Comment: @DaveNewton The rails console gives me "←[1m←[35mAchievementResult Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "achievement_results".* FROM "achievement_results" WHERE "achievement_results"."achievement_id" = 2 => []". Not aware of another way to check the db.

Comment: @MichałKwiatkowski Added the model to the question, in the view the count shows 0.

Comment: Then what does `@achievement.achievement_results.each{|r| puts(r.inspect)}` return in the console?

Comment: I meant check the DB directly; `each` simply won't iterate over something that isn't there, and you wouldn't get null values, you'd get a NilValue for `result`, so *something* is in the list.

Comment: Check if you are rendering the view twice due to some bad code. See if could you be rendering the view with the `:collection` option also? Add some text to the view and see if that text shows up when you render - it is possible you have another view with similar content. Triple check that you are working on the correct view file in the correct git(?) branch. Check that the Rails console is open for the correct app and branch as well.

Comment: @MichałKwiatkowski []
Dave, what's the easiest way to check the db? I'm not totally familiar with rails.
Zabba, not 100% on how to check that, but it's always only 1 rogue iteration, and the rest of the page isn't duplicated

Comment: If it helps, <%= result %> gives #<AchievementResult:0x3e2db98>, so I guess it's finding an object somehow

Comment: How is `@achievement` derived in the controller?

Comment: There's nothing extra in the database itself. Removing all entries from the database still shows the extra entry

Comment: @Septih I am interested in this answer as well, I've had this happen to me too and it is maddening.

Comment: Have a look at the contents of achievement.achievement_results. Add a line before the iteration like this: <%= @achievement.achievement_results.inspect %> - this should prove whether the nulls are in the enumerable or not. If they are, try inspecting the array in the controller (just add a puts line in the action method)

Comment: Can we see the controller code? @ achievement is defined as an instance variable, so for example, if your controller is going @ achievement.achievement_results << AchievementResult.new, it won't show up in the database, as you haven't saved it, but it will still be assigned to the object, so will show up in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a line such as `@achievement.achievement_results.build` being called somewhere (maybe the controller, or in a form somewhere?). This would explain why `count` returns a different number (as `count` is not cached like `size`) and why the values are null.

If you do have that line, changing it to `AchievementResults.new(:achievement => @achievement)` will probably sort you out.