# Rails .Build causing extra item in each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a basic to do list app that does simple CRUD based on current_user (generated via Devise).

On the index there is an extra item when using <% @tasks.each do |task| %>. The extra item doesn't have id (/tasks).  After doing some research, it might be caused by the .build in the controller as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963116/getting-a-rogue-iteration-from-my-each-loop). How do you get around/fix this extra item problem? I am also using ajax to refresh the crud however I believe the extra item is messing with how the new list is rendered after create/delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid it when you check for new record:

```
unless task.new_record?
  #other tasks stuff
end
```

Comment: thank you for the response. It looks like that avoids the extra item after I create/delete and it renders again. But initially the whole list is not showing, so I only see the list after I create something (nothing to delete)