# Cannot delete Nil data that is not in table

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm relatively new to ruby on rails and building a basic application in rails 3 and mac osx8.

I was experiencing an extra and blank data set in an each loop iteration in a view, here:

```
<% @exercise.instruction_types.each do |instruction_type| %>
            <li><a href="#tab<%= instruction_type.id %>" data-toggle="tab"><%= instruction_order %>. <%= instruction_type.name %></a></li>
            <% instruction_order = instruction_order + 1 %>
<% end %>
```

This was creating an extra and blank li item in the show. When I load that view, I see an extra iteration of the loop with null values for the result fields. This happens even when the array is [].

Instruction_type model:

```
class InstructionType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :instructions
  has_many :exercises, :through => :instructions
  attr_accessible :name 
end
```

Here is the controller:

```
def play
    ..
    @instruction_types = @exercise.instruction_types.build
    ..
end
```

After some research and following advice from here [Getting a rogue iteration from my .each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963116/getting-a-rogue-iteration-from-my-each-loop)
I pludded in this instance variable inspection placed in my view.html.erb

```
<%= @exercise.instruction_types.inspect %>
```

Rendered view output

```
[#<InstructionType id: 1, name: "Content", created_at: "2013-06-03 03:11:56", updated_at:     "2013-06-03 03:11:56">,...
<InstructionType id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

I would like to know how that nil data was created, how I can prevent it in the future, and how I can delete it now.

Comment: `@exercise.instruction_types.build` creates an empty associated instance which is not yet persisted to the database

Comment: Thanks for the quick response phoet. I've also googled how to deal with that but I haven't figured it out, would you be able to instruct further? Do I want to delete it somehow, persist it to the db? How do I get it to stop appearing in my each loop?

Comment: I guess my follow up to this is is there another way I can access instruction_type data in my exercise views other than the @exercise.instruction_type.build command in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `play` action isn't supposed to build a new `InstructionType` (which is what I gather from the comments), just remove the `.build` call. If it *is*, make sure to call `.save` on the `InstructionType` as well.